How to check if label is defined only later
I would like to know when in my manuscript, I am refereeing to labels that are defined only later. Is there a way to list, e.g. in the log file, all cases when when executing \ref the corresponding \label only occurs later in the source code.
As an example. Compiling the following code
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a nice equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
   E=mc^2\,.
\end{equation}
It is much cooler than the following equation (\ref{eq:2}). Note than (\ref{eq:1}) was found 200 year later than
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
   F=ma\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}

Should produce a warning along the lines "Warning: \ref{eq:2} in line xxx occurs before the corresponding label". While no such warning is issued for \ref{eq:1}.

welcome! why do you want to know exactly? you can certainly do that - just compare the page number for the label with the current page number when referencing and write out a line if the former is greater than the latter. (or do you need to know even if the label is later on the same page or, even, line? then you'd need to ensure that information was recorded etc.)  but it's hard to think of a use-case where you'd need to know this (and cross-refs are still the best strategy). so it feels a bit like an xy problem?

I want to reorder some long set of notes. My plan was to reorder some sections and subsections. It turns out that, at least in my field, the good style is to refer to equations that occur earlier in the manuscript while referring to equations that occur later should be best avoided. So I wanted to know if there is an efficient way of checking that, after reordering, I do not suddenly have many references where I am referring to a point later in the text.

ok, that makes sense. so you really need it temporarily. that is, you could do something like redefine the cross-reference commands you use to print warnings in the log or whatever. but you should provide a minimal working example in your question so people have code to test with.

it is rather easy to differentiate both on the first compilation, but there is no good hook for follow-up compilation and you would have to redefine internal commands or define a new \checkref command.

This does it:
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{% things may happen at begin document and I am too lazy to
                 % check what kernel does so let's delay too
 \let\oldlabel\label
 \def\label#1{\global\expandafter\let\csname
               THISISALABELNAME\detokenize{#1}\endcsname\empty\oldlabel{#1}}
 \let\oldref\ref
 % unfortunately current kernel \ref definition is done using a LaTeX3 wrapper
 % to support starred variant I guess and other variants, I don't have time
 % to try to reproduce that here so the new \ref loses this as it grabs
 % a mandartory argument with no further ado
 \protected\def\ref#1{\unless\ifcsname THISISALABELNAME\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
   \PackageWarning{MYSELF}{\string\ref{\detokenize{#1}} occurs before the
     corresponding label}\fi
     \oldref{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
This is a nice equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
   E=mc^2\,.
\end{equation}
It is much cooler than the following equation (\ref{eq:2}). Note than (\ref{eq:1}) was found 200 year later than
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
   F=ma\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}

Executing pdflatex produces this console output (and in log too):
No file zut3.aux.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:2' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.


Package MYSELF Warning: \ref{eq:2} occurs before the corresponding label on inp
ut line 24.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.


[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./zut3.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


on first run, then only
(./zut3.aux)

Package MYSELF Warning: \ref{eq:2} occurs before the corresponding label on inp
ut line 24.


[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

on second run.
Note that the line number referred to is the one of location of \ref not \label although the wording may let one infer the contrary, we should play with \PackageWarningNoLine and issue outself the suitable \on@line.
please ping me if you like better wording

I am utterly sorry that I got the logic wrong in the first version. I am thus editing my answer now. The initial version warned when \ref was used after \label which is not what was asked for.  Fortunately I checked before bedtime...
